# Force Postgres to write log to a new file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've updated the value of `log_line_prefix`, and I wanted that the log file will contain only logs with the new prefix.

I deleted the log file (`postgresql-9.3-main.log`), assuming that once the file is gone, postgres will just create a new one, but that is not the case, and now the is no log file.

I read somewhere that the server still holds the fp, and this is why it doesn't create a new file.

Restarting the service will probably solve the issue, but I can't do that now.
Is there a way to tell the service to create a new log file?

Comment: What if you change the value for `log_filename`?

Comment: it didn't work. But I suspect that `log_filename` is not used because it's value is `postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log` but the actual file name is `postgresql-9.3-main.log`

Comment: Did you reload configuration ?

Comment: @saphapasci I have a similar problem, and a postgresql reload does not work (I actually came here to try find an alternative to having to do a restart)